# Compare three columns and add a fourth

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup, worksheet-function

I want to compare Column C and Column B and copy the matching Column A value in Column D, row by row.

```
A                    B                     C
192.132.14.1    IND-EDU-ROUTER-01   BOB-POL-ROUTER-01
192.132.27.1    IND-POL-ROUTER-01   DHL-TEA-ROUTER-01
192.241.173.1   CHN-EDU-ROUTER-01   IND-POL-ROUTER-01
192.31.27.1     CHN-POL-ROUTER-01   DHL-MKT-ROUTER-01
192.31.17.1     CHN-MGM-ROUTER-01   BOB-POL-ROUTER-01
192.61.27.1     BOB-POL-ROUTER-01   KEL-TEA-ROUTER-01
192.141.14.1    ASK-MGM-ROUTER-01   CHN-MGM-ROUTER-01
192.36.15.1     KEL-EDU-ROUTER-01   DHL-TEA-ROUTER-02
192.36.11.1     KEL-TEA-ROUTER-01   KEL-TEA-ROUTER-01
192.36.14.1     KEL-TRD-ROUTER-01   IND-EDU-ROUTER-01
192.71.16.1     DHL-MKT-ROUTER-01   IND-POL-ROUTER-01
192.71.14.1     DHL-TEA-ROUTER-01   CHN-EDU-ROUTER-01
192.71.15.1     DHL-TEA-ROUTER-02   CHN-POL-ROUTER-01
```

My result should look like this:

```
A                      B                 C                  D
192.132.14.1    IND-EDU-ROUTER-01   BOB-POL-ROUTER-01   192.61.27.1
192.132.27.1    IND-POL-ROUTER-01   DHL-TEA-ROUTER-01   192.71.14.1
192.241.173.1   CHN-EDU-ROUTER-01   IND-POL-ROUTER-01   192.132.27.1
192.31.27.1     CHN-POL-ROUTER-01   DHL-MKT-ROUTER-01   192.71.16.1
192.31.17.1     CHN-MGM-ROUTER-01   BOB-POL-ROUTER-01   192.61.27.1
192.61.27.1     BOB-POL-ROUTER-01   KEL-TEA-ROUTER-01   192.36.11.1
192.141.14.1    ASK-MGM-ROUTER-01   CHN-MGM-ROUTER-01   192.31.17.1
192.36.15.1     KEL-EDU-ROUTER-01   DHL-TEA-ROUTER-02   192.71.15.1
192.36.11.1     KEL-TEA-ROUTER-01   KEL-TEA-ROUTER-01   192.36.11.1
192.36.14.1     KEL-TRD-ROUTER-01   IND-EDU-ROUTER-01   192.132.14.1
192.71.16.1     DHL-MKT-ROUTER-01   IND-POL-ROUTER-01   192.132.27.1
192.71.14.1     DHL-TEA-ROUTER-01   CHN-EDU-ROUTER-01   192.241.173.1
192.71.15.1     DHL-TEA-ROUTER-02   CHN-POL-ROUTER-01   192.31.27.1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to format that data - its impossible to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Use Vlookup after inserting a copy of column A between column B and C.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C2,B:B,0))
```

copied down to suit.

In effect MATCH finds how far down the contents of C2 are found in ColumnB and then takes the corresponding cell value from ColumnA for that row. A consequence is that duplicate entries may not produce desired results.